# Changing RSA passphrase on Windows with TortoiseGit auxiliary programs?

Tags: rsa, private-key

We have designers who are on PCs and are starting to use our git version control repositories. we are using rsa keys to allow them to connect, and TortoiseGit as the interface.

Everything is working well, but when we give them their rsa private key and communicate their rsa passphrase to them, we want them to change it to something only they know. Our developers can change the passphrase in a Linux shell, but we don't have that on the designer's computers.

Is there something that comes with the TortoiseGit requirements, or some other simple program that will allow them to change their rsa passphrase once they get their private key?

Comment: It sound sot me like you are doing things backwards.  If you create the private keys and then give them the keys, they are not private.  They should be generating the keys themselves and giving you the public key.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with TortoiseGit, so I don't know what kind of RSA keys you're referring to, but if they're SSH keys, you might be able to use [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html)'s PuTTYgen.